# RegEx for matching two single quotes from start and end of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, ecmascript-6

I need to replace two quotes at the beginning and end of elements with one quote.

My code is:

```
const regex = /['']/g;
let categories = [];
let categoryArray = data.categories.split(','); // ''modiles2'', ''Men''s Apparel'', ''Women''s Apparel'', ''Jeans'', ''Sneakers''
    for (let value of Object.values(categoryArray)) {
        categories.push(categoryArray[i].replace(regex, '\''));
    }
}
return categories 
// What should be 'modiles2','Men''s Apparel','Women''s Apparel','Jeans','Sneakers'
// What comes back ''modiles2'',''Men''s Apparel'',''Women''s Apparel'',''Jeans'',''Sneakers''
```

My regular expression replaces only the first of two quotation marks with one quotation mark.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `const regex = /['']/g;` check out what *character classes* are.

Comment: @Rafael If I use '\' \ '', it replaces only at the beginning, I need both at the beginning and at the end, in the middle I don’t need to touch

Comment: Do all elements in the array have `'''` at the start and end? Because then you could just slice each value: `elements.map(str => str.slice(1, -1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character classes look for any *single* character between the brackets. Character classes that have duplicate characters, like `['']`, can do without such duplication.

```js
"''modiles2'',''Men''s Apparel'',''Women''s Apparel'',''Jeans'',''Sneakers''"
    .split(',')
    .forEach(s => console.log( s.replace(/^''|''$/g, '\'') ))
```

Comment: Good point about the regex classes. But you don't need to capture the groups for the replacement. It's additional (mini) overhead in this case.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point. I meant to use non-capturing groups, but I ended up removing them. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Rafael I tried to reproduce this and I have a problem: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JVeMgX

Comment: Your codepen's `data` string is delimited by `, ` (with a trailing space) --- `split()` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to match two quotation marks - use this regex:

```
const regex = /^'.*'$/g;
```

Comment: That will replace all double quotes. I think OP wants it only at beginning and end.

Comment: There is no need to escape `'`. It doesn't have a special meaning in regular expressions.

Comment: Really @FelixKling? I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You can find a list here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_special_characters

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern uses a character class `['']` which matches any of the listed which could be written as `[']` which is just `'`

If there can be more than 2 at the start or at the end, you could also use a [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `{2,}` to match 2 or more single quotes and replace with a single quote. To match exactly 2 single quotes use `''`.

```
^'{2,}|'{2,}$
```

- `^'{2,}` Match 2 or more quotes at the start of the string
- `|` Or
- `'{2,}$` Match 2 or more single quotes at the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WlBAhJ/1)

Use the `/g` global flag to replace all occurrences.

```js
console.log("''modiles2'',''Men''s Apparel'',''Women''s Apparel'',''Jeans'',''Sneakers''"
.split(',')
.map(s => s.replace(/^'{2,}|'{2,}$/g, "'")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my two cents, in one line:

```
return data.categories.split(',').map(val => val.trim().replace(/^'{2,}|'{2,}$/, "'"));
```

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/6KMsj7/1) might help to do so. You might consider using <kbd>\x27</kbd> instead of <kbd>'</kbd> just to be safe.

```
^(\x27{2,})(.+)(\x27{2,})$
```

[image]

This RegEx creates three groups, just to be simple, and you might use <kbd>$2</kbd>, which is your target output.